# How to Parse Timezone Datetime objects with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

So, rather simply:
have columns with dates like this: "2000-05-30 17:27:00-05:00"

```
    data                   open high    low close
0   2000-05-30 17:27:00-05:00   0.9302  0.9302  0.9302  0.9302
1   2000-05-30 17:35:00-05:00   0.9304  0.9305  0.9304  0.9305
2   2000-05-30 17:38:00-05:00   0.9304  0.9304  0.9303  0.9303
3   2000-05-30 17:43:00-05:00   0.9301  0.9301  0.9300  0.9300
4   2000-05-30 17:44:00-05:00   0.9298  0.9298  0.9297  0.9297
```

I have tried the custom parser:

```
custom_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S-%z")
data = pd.read_csv('eurusd_2.csv', parse_dates=[0], date_parser=custom_parser, parse_dates=True)
```

but this doesn't work; I think it is due to the ":" in the timezone "-05:00" - any solutions for this?

Is there a way to specify the timezone format similar to how specifies the year/month/day format?

Many thanks in advance,

C

Answer (score 0):

The simple:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=['data'], sep='\s\s+')
```

seems to work. `df['data']` is:

```
0   2000-05-30 17:27:00-05:00
1   2000-05-30 17:35:00-05:00
2   2000-05-30 17:38:00-05:00
3   2000-05-30 17:43:00-05:00
4   2000-05-30 17:44:00-05:00
Name: data, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-300)]
```

Maybe your data contains some irregularities.